# $\operatorname{Fr}( p(\overline U) )$ where $p : X \to Y$ is a closed, not necessarily continuous, surjection, and $U \subset X$ is open

Tags: general-topology

Question:

> Let $p : X \rightarrow Y$ be a closed (not necessarily continuous) surjection. If $U$ is open, then  $$\operatorname{Fr} ( p(\overline U) ) \subset p(\overline U ) \cap p(X - U).$$

I know that $\operatorname{Fr} (p(\overline U )) =\overline{p(\overline U)} \cap \overline{p(\overline U)^c} = p(\overline U) \cap \overline{p(\overline U)^c}$.

Let $p(x) \in p(\overline U) \cap \overline{p(\overline U)^c}$. How can one show that $x \in X-U$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @ Arthur Fischer : Its look better, thanks

Comment: What does $Fr$ mean?